# VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest not returning any matches

Tags: ios, ios11, detection, face-detection

I'm using the following code, almost verbatim from the WWDC video, Xcode 9, iPhone 8.  The CIDetector is returning facial images, but this isn't:

```
        let faceDetectionRequest = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest()
        let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(rawValue: UInt32(image!.imageOrientation.rawValue))
        let myRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImageRef, orientation: .down, options: [ : ])
        do {
             try myRequestHandler.perform([faceDetectionRequest])

            for observation in faceDetectionRequest.results as! [VNFaceObservation] {
                print("found a face")
            }
        } catch {
            print("error is ", error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

I'm only looking for faces in one orientation, which is .right.  I have tried a few other orientations just to see, but no luck.

Has anyone had any success with this?